# CUDA Thrust sort or CUB::DeviceRadixSort

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust, cub

I have a pool of particles represented by an array of float4 where the w component is the particle's current lifetime in the range [0, 1].

I need to sort this array based on the lifetime of the particles in descending order so that I can keep an accurate counter for how many particles are currently "active" (lifetime greater than 0). I need this counter because it will allow me to index into the correct spot in the array when I need to activate more particles (which happens randomly).

My array of particles is stored in device memory and it seems like I should be able to sort the array without having to transfer the array to host memory.

I haven't had much luck in finding examples online that show how I could do this with either Thrust or CUB. In addition, I am hesitant to use Thrust because I don't know how to prevent it from degrading into merge-sort (which is far slower than radix sort) since I need to sort based on the w component. As for CUB, I simply haven't found any resources at all as to how I could do this.

I would also prefer to keep the lifetime stored within the w component since this makes my life significantly easier in other parts of my code.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: In either cub or thrust, we could sort on the `.w` "keys" only, doing a key-value sort where the values are just a linear incrementing index (both cub and thrust offer fancy iterators to auto-generate the index sequence).  We could then use the resultant rearrangement of the index sequence to reorder the `float4` array in one step to be sorted by `.w`.  This would allow  you to retain the radix sorting speed (in either cub or thrust) and might also be fairly efficient since the `float4` quantities only need to be moved/rearranged once, rather than successively moved during the sort operation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Would you be able to provide a code example of this? I am not sure how you could specify that the w component is the key? This way I could mark you as the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either cub or thrust, we could sort on the `.w` "keys" only, doing a key-value sort where the values are just a linear incrementing index:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

We could then use the resultant rearrangement of the index sequence to reorder the original `float4` array in one step (effectively sorted by `.w`). This would allow you to retain the radix sorting speed (in either cub or thrust) and might also be fairly efficient since the `float4` quantities only need to be moved/rearranged once, rather than successively moved during the sort operation.

Here is a fully worked example in thrust, on 32M elements, demonstrating an "ordinary" thrust sort, using a functor to specify sorting on the `.w` element (`sort_f4_w`), followed be the approach described above.  In this case, on my particular setup (Fedora 20, CUDA 7, Quadro5000), the 2nd approach seems to be about 5x faster:

```
$ cat t686.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <vector_types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/equal.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

#define DSIZE (32*1048576)

struct sort_f4_w
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const float4 &a, const float4 &b) const {
    return (a.w < b.w);}
};
// functor to extract the .w element from a float4
struct f4_to_fw : public thrust::unary_function<float4, float>
{
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(const float4 &a) const {
    return a.w;}
};
// functor to extract the .x element from a float4
struct f4_to_fx : public thrust::unary_function<float4, float>
{
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(const float4 &a) const {
    return a.x;}
};


bool validate(thrust::device_vector<float4> &d1, thrust::device_vector<float4> &d2){
  return thrust::equal(thrust::make_transform_iterator(d1.begin(), f4_to_fx()), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d1.end(), f4_to_fx()), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d2.begin(), f4_to_fx()));
}


int main(){
  unsigned long long t1_time, t2_time;
  float4 *mydata = new float4[DSIZE];
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++){
    mydata[i].x = i;
    mydata[i].y = i;
    mydata[i].z = i;
    mydata[i].w = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;}

  thrust::host_vector<float4>   h_data(mydata, mydata+DSIZE);
  // do once as a warm-up run, then report timings on second run
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    thrust::device_vector<float4> d_data1 = h_data;
    thrust::device_vector<float4> d_data2 = h_data;

  // first time sort using typical thrust approach
    t1_time = dtime_usec(0);
    thrust::sort(d_data1.begin(), d_data1.end(), sort_f4_w());
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    t1_time = dtime_usec(t1_time);
  // now extract keys and create index values, sort, then rearrange
    t2_time = dtime_usec(0);
    thrust::device_vector<float> keys(DSIZE);
    thrust::device_vector<int> vals(DSIZE);
    thrust::copy(thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_data2.begin(), f4_to_fw()), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_data2.end(), f4_to_fw()), keys.begin());
    thrust::sequence(vals.begin(), vals.end());
    thrust::sort_by_key(keys.begin(), keys.end(), vals.begin());
    thrust::device_vector<float4> result(DSIZE);
    thrust::copy(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_data2.begin(), vals.begin()), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_data2.begin(), vals.end()), result.begin());
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    t2_time = dtime_usec(t2_time);
    if (!validate(d_data1, result)){
      std::cout << "Validation failure " << std::endl;
      }
    }
  std::cout << "thrust t1 time: " << t1_time/(float)USECPSEC << "s, t2 time: " << t2_time/(float)USECPSEC << std::endl;
}


$ nvcc -o t686 t686.cu
$ ./t686
thrust t1 time: 0.731456s, t2 time: 0.149959
$
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without first creating a host vector and then making a device vector? For example, my array of float4s is already stored in device memory (and this needs to be performed every frame/iteration).

Comment: Yes, there is no particular need for the (single) host vector (`h_data`) in my example, except that it is a convenient way to initialize the data for demonstration purposes (it could be eliminated easily with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` operations...).  It should be clear that all of the work is being done on device data that is resident on the GPU.